# Error using Vlookup function in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have the following data set:

[image]

I calculate the maximum return using `=max(B2:B13)` in cell `D3` (i.e., 13.55%), and then I would like to find the date where this maximum return was realized. Thus, I use `=vlookup(D3;A2:B13;1;FALSE)`, and I get as a result `#N/A`, which is clearly wrong. How can I make this work?

Comment: You need to put column A in column C and lookup that way.

Comment: It's not wrong - you're using it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a VLOOKUP to find a value that isn't in the first column of your data table. Use an INDEX/MATCH formula instead:

```
=INDEX(A2:A13,MATCH(MAX(B2:B13),B2:B13,0))
```

A VLOOKUP is a **V**ertical **Lookup** - and is used to look up a value in the first column of a table and return a corresponding value from another column in that table (just like looking at a timetable for example).

You are trying to find the max value from column B, in column A - where it doesn't exist so you're not going to find it. In order to use a VLOOKUP the `lookup_value` **must** be in the first column of the data table.

If you want to look up a value in another column of the data table, then you need to use `=INDEX(MATCH())` instead.

Comment: to be clear, the OP *can* use a vlookup, if they transpose the data in column A and B, so that the returns are in column A and dates in column B (something similar to what @findwindow initially mentioned).

Comment: I meant it couldn't be used to look up a value not in the first column - but admittedly very poorly worded. I'll edit it though, cheers :)

Comment: Both approaches work, but I get `41001` instead of the date.

Comment: @findwindow - yeah you do, when I learned it, I never went back to `Vlookup` (unless it's a super simple lookup I need). Index/Match is my jam.

Comment: @findwindow index/match also saves a **lot** of processing power if you're using really big data sets because you're only looking at 2 columns instead of an entire table

Comment: @Egodym don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped (green tick to the left) ;)

Comment: @MacroMan - to be fair, I made my comment before you edited your post with all the explanation :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I still had to edit again to correct the wording so perfectly valid! no sweat! :)